# Sort a data frame for a value

Tags: r, dataframe, indices

I really dont know how to translate this question so i will just explain it.

I am having this data set:

```
    > f1
    species weight length3  sex
1         1  242.0    30.0 <NA>
2         1  290.0    31.2 <NA>
3         1  340.0    31.1 <NA>
4         1  363.0    33.5 <NA>
5         1  430.0    34.0 <NA>
6         1  450.0    34.7 <NA>
7         1  500.0    34.5 <NA>
```

(158 rows in total). Species goes from 1 to 7. Now i want a subset only with species of 7. I have tried

```
f1["species" == 7]
```

Also the following does work

```
f1[104:159,]
```

But this only works since this data set is sorted nicely, if for example values from 1-7 where distributed in any other random way this would not work.

But this unfortunatelly doesnt work. Can someone help please?

Comment: You need a comma, `f1[f1$species==7,]` or `f1[f1[["species"]]==7,]`

Answer (score 1):

You are indexing the dataframe wrong. When idexing, you should use `[row, column]`.

So, in your example, you should use `f1[f1$species==7,]`.

Explanation:

`f1$species==7` returns a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values. With that vector you are indexing your dataframe rows (only TRUE values).

After the `,` you don't specify any column, this will (by default) get all columns available in the dataframe.

Comment: f1[f1$species==7,] did it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- f1 %>% filter(species == 7)
```

Or

```
df <- subset(f1, species == 7)
```